# React Native: Is it bad to store a TextInput value not in the state but in a class property to avoid rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While working with TextInput components I stumbled over this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11631

tl;dr: putting state in a value-property on a TextInput that changes that value in each onChangeText breaks the visuals if secureTextEntry is also set.

```
// Broken
<TextInput
    placeholder="Password"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    value={this.state.password1}
    onChangeText={(password1) => this.setState({ password1 })}
/>
// Works
<TextInput
    placeholder="Password"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    onChangeText={(password2) => this.setState({ password2 })}
/>
```

A workaround for this issue is to just not use state and avoid the rerendering of the component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    props: {
        onSubmit: (password: string) => void
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.password = password}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => {this.props.onSubmit(this.password)}}
                    title="Submit"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This feelds incredibly hacky and wrong though, but things like a component that wraps TextInput and needs to restore its current value on a rerender has to do something like this. This is kinda what TextInput itself does: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a6df7a6/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L774-L795

Comment: It's not hacky, it's fine to store values outside of the component state. You should only use state if you want to update something else as the user types into the TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your component re-rendering scenario.

for example:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.someProperty != nextState.someProperty
}
```

[shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)